# how to make ean13 unique in odoo8

Tags: postgresql, odoo-8, ean-13

I need to create a module in Odoov8 that can make ean13 field in product.template unique.

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError

class uniq_barcode(models.Model):

    inherit = "product.template"

    ean13 = fields.Char()
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('ean13_uniq', 'unique(ean13)', _('code bare exisite deja !')),
    ]
```

But it's not working! I'm working on this since yesterday

Comment: Why don't you simply create a unique index on that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey guys i dunno why _sql_constraints is not working but i tried something else and its working ! here's the code

```
class uni_barcode(models.Model):
_inherit = "product.product"


@api.one
@api.constrains('company_id', 'ean13', 'active')
def check_unique_company_and_ean13(self):
    if self.active and self.ean13 and self.company_id:
        filters = [('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id),
                   ('ean13', '=', self.ean13), ('active', '=', True)]
        prod_ids = self.search(filters)
        if len(prod_ids) > 1:
            raise Warning(
                _('Code bare existe deja !!'))
```

voila problem résolu
merci

Answer (score 0):

This code will not run because your model did not inherit from 'product.template'. You declared `inherit = "product.template"`, it should be `_inherit = "product.template"`, don't forget `_`

Comment: i'll check this out :D

Comment: well actually in my code it was with _inherit
still not working